# HelperList action 'delete' does not receive the ID

Tags: prestashop

I've created a list which is fully populated with records from database. I'd like to add a button 'delete' in order to delete records on demand. The button appears, but whenever it makes a request, it does not have an ID of the record I want to delete. The URL looks like this:

```
controller=AdminModules&configure=estimateddelivery&=&deleteestimateddelivery&token=6d1625ddf520e0bf8d2c43bea84f21d3
```

There is a `&=&` which if I understand correctly should be populated with something like `&id=10&`. I am not sure what the problem is or where to look at. I've check code examples of similar functionalities and it looks like I am doing everything the same way.

```
public function renderList()
    {  
        $this->$fields_list = [
            'id_estimateddelivery' => [
                'title' => $this->l('ID'),
                'type' =>'text',
            ],
            'from' => [
                'title' => $this->l('Delivery period from')
            ],
            'to' => [
                'title' => $this->l('Delivery period to')
            ],
            'countries' => [
                'title' => $this->l('Countries applicable'),
                'type' => 'text'
            ]
        ];

        $helper = new HelperList();
        $helper->module = $this;
        $helper->shopLinkType = '';
        $helper->simple_header = true;
        $helper->idientifier = 'id_estimateddelivery';
        $helper->actions = [
            'delete'
        ];
        $helper->show_toolbar = false;
        $helper->title = $this->l('List of created estimated deliveries');
        $helper->table = $this->name;
        $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
        $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex . '&configure=' . $this->name;

        return $helper->generateList($this->getEstimatedDeliveries(), $this->$fields_list);
    }
```

```
public function deleteEstimatedDelivery()
{
    return Db::getInstance()->execute('DELETE FROM '. _DB_PREFIX_ .'estimateddelivery WHERE `id_estimateddelivery` = '. (int)Tools::getValue('id_estimateddelivery'));
}
```

```
else if(Tools::isSubmit('delete' . $this->name))
{
    if(!$this->deleteEstimatedDelivery())
        $output . $this->displayError($this->l('An error occured during link deletion'));
    else
        $output . $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('The estimated delivery has been deleted'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though there was no error message, the code line: `$helper->idientifier = 'id_estimateddelivery';` had a typo. Should have been `identifier`.